# How can I map a key index into each element of a data.table or data.frame object in R with a key/pair index?

Tags: r, data.table

I currently have the following data.table in `R`:

```
tab <- data.table(Col1=c("Grade1","Grade2","Grade2"),Col2=c("Grade3","Grade3","Grade1"),Col3=c("Grade1","Grade2","Grade3"))
> tab
     Col1   Col2   Col3
1: Grade1 Grade3 Grade1
2: Grade2 Grade3 Grade2
3: Grade2 Grade1 Grade3
```

I would like to map it according to an index/value table:

```
kvtab <- data.table(Key=c("Grade1","Grade2","Grade3"),Value=c(1,2,3))
> kvtab
      Key Value
1: Grade1     1
2: Grade2     2
3: Grade3     3
```

so that I can get:

```
   Col1 Col2 Col3
1:    1    3    1
2:    2    3    2
3:    2    1    3
```

How can I create the joins or merges here when there are multiple columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Repeated update joins

This joins each column of `tab` with the *lookup table* `kvtab` and replaces the values accordingly:

```
library(data.table)
for (col in colnames(tab)) tab[kvtab, on = sprintf("%s==Key", col), (col) := Value][]
tab
```

> ```
>      Col1   Col2   Col3
> 1:      1      3      1
> 2:      2      3      2
> 3:      2      1      3
> ```

#### Trivial solutions

which only work for the given sample dataset by may fail for other usecases

Removing the substring `Grade` from each element:

```
tab[, lapply(.SD, function(x) stringr::str_remove(x, "Grade"))]
```

Or, turning each column into a factor and returning the factor levels:

```
tab[, lapply(.SD, function(x) as.integer(factor(x, levels = kvtab$Key)))]
```

> ```
>     Col1  Col2  Col3
>    <int> <int> <int>
> 1:     1     3     1
> 2:     2     3     2
> 3:     2     1     3
> ```

Note that the `levels` parameter is required to ensure that all columns share the same factor levels.

Answer (score 0):

With `lapply` and `match`:

```
tab[,colnames(tab):=lapply(.SD,function(x) kvtab$Value[match(x,kvtab$Key)])][]

   Col1 Col2 Col3
1:    1    3    1
2:    2    3    2
3:    2    1    3
```

Comment: What does the "[]" do at the end?

Comment: `[]` displays the result of the previous assignement by reference. If you remove it, the calculation is done without output.